# How understand "All the methods of estimation are invariant under linear transformations of the data"?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, simulation

In this [paper](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj-_92PsNf7AhWNkmoFHRSLC3IQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.cmu.edu%2Ftechnometrics%2F80-89%2FVOL-27-03%2Fv2703251.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2e0Kf2OepSHw-FEc_IVi0f), the authors compare different methods of fitting generalized extreme value distribution (such as the maximum likelihood method). For example, the Gumbel distribution:

$$
F(x)=\exp\left(-\exp\left(-\frac{x-\xi}{\alpha}\right)\right)
$$

The authors design a simulation to compare these estimators. On page 255, below Figure 4, why do the authors say

> All the methods of estimation are invariant under linear transformations of the data, so without loss of generality the location and scale parameters $\xi=0$ and $\alpha=1$ were used throughout.

Here is the snap of the relevant page:

[image]

I think if we take other $\mu, \sigma$ values may also lead to different results for these estimators? Why does the author say that this is invariant?

Comment: Are you sure this paper uses MLE?  I haven't read it, but its title and abstract focus on using *moments* for estimation.  This is a location-scale family.  It you're unsure what this means or implies, then please check out [our posts on the topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=location+scale+family).

Comment: Yes, on page 255.

Comment: Seriously?? The paper is behind a paywall.

Comment: The authors compare MLE and method of moments. But that's not the question I wanted to ask. I mainly want to ask why the authors only need to consider the special case of $\mu=0, \sigma=1$ (as true values) in the simulation and then calculate the MSE to compare which estimator performs well. How about other possible value of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: That's what you seem to be asking in your previous question, so my recommendation is the same: learn about the meaning of location and scale.

Comment: Does this statement by the author (which I quoted) make sense?

Comment: What statement?  If you mean the quotation in your question, nobody can check that without reading the paper or at least trusting its premise.  If its premise is true, then its conclusion follows.

Comment: @whuber The author said so directly when doing the simulation. He also did not explain, and reading this article should not have anything to do with... There is no proof.

Comment: @whuber I found a free version and I put the link in my question now.

Comment: MLE is invariant under any transformation. That's a basic fact that is usually taught when you learn about MLE, it should be available in most textbooks of your preference, or even on [this very website](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438778/question-about-casella-and-bergers-proof-of-mle-invariance).

Comment: Whether MoM is invariant depends on what you measure unlike MLE.  Wrt to "I think if we take other μ,σ values may also lead to different results for these estimators? Why does the author say that this is invariant?". In statistics, the meaning of "invariant" is a bit different from general math, because you look at the things through the lens of the decision theory. The implied invariance is of the action taken that depends on a measure or its transformation, not its value per se. In the strict math sense they would be called equivariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that the Gumbel distribution models the maximum temperature in a year. Would it matter if you use a Celsius temperature scale or a Fahrenheit temperature scale? No, the estimates will just shift and scale, but the properties, like efficiency, or relative variance ratios, remain the same.

If you perform simulations with a specific $\alpha = 1$ and $\xi = 0$ then the results will be relatively the same as when you would have performed simulations with other values (up to some shift and scaling).

Say you simulate the estimates $\hat{\xi}$ with some given true $\xi$ that produces variables $x$. If instead you would have made simulations with some different scale $x^\prime = a + bx$, then the estimate $\hat{\xi}^\prime$ for $x^\prime$ would be just a re-scaled value of the estimate $\hat{\xi}$ for the unscaled variables $x$.